# CSS Not formatting correctly

Tags: html, css

Today was the first time I have ever used HTML and CSS, and I am trying to make a little personal website, to expand my skills and knowledge.

I am writing the CSS styles for my homepage, and I can't seem to get the file to format correctly, and I'm afraid that my code isn't working;

```
.navigation {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: "arial, helvetica, serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color:rgba(240, 255, 255, 0.5);
  outline-style: outset;
  outline-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
}

.news {
    float: right;
     padding: 20px;
  font-family: "arial, helvetica, serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color:rgba(240, 255, 255, 0.5);
  outline-style: outset;
  outline-color: grey;

 .infobox1 {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
  font-family: "arial, helvetica, serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color:rgba(240, 255, 255, 0.5);
  outline-style: outset;
  outline-color: grey;
 }
```

I understand this is a super stupid question, but just wondered if anyone could help me properly set out my CSS code. Thanks!

Comment: `font-family: "arial, helvetica, serif;` <--

Comment: if you checked the syntax highlighting, you can see that you are missing a double qoute on the lines that state `font-family: "arial, helvetica, serif;`. To fix, just replace it with `font-family: "arial, helvetica, serif";`

Comment: Thank you! can't believe I didn't see that!

Comment: Why did i get a -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an edited version of your css code it should work just fine.
copy and paste to use.

Hope this helps.

```
.navigation {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color:rgba(240, 255, 255, 0.5);
  outline-style: outset;
  outline-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
}

.news {
    float: right;
     padding: 20px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color:rgba(240, 255, 255, 0.5);
  outline-style: outset;
  outline-color: grey;
}
 .infobox1 {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color:rgba(240, 255, 255, 0.5);
  outline-style: outset;
  outline-color: grey;
 }
```